# JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object. in asp.net core

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a web api using asp.net core and cosmos db.I create a api for get all item.I got the following error.I provide all my repository , controller code blow. please help me to find out what did i wrong??

Controller code:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> FetchListAsync(
        [FromQuery]Guid? itemId)
    {
        var result =
            await _catalogRepository.FetchListAsync(
                itemId);

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Repository code:

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Catalog>> FetchListAsync(
           Guid? itemId)
        {

            var feedOptions =
                  new FeedOptions
                  {
                      MaxItemCount = -1,
                      EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
                  };
            var query = new SqlQuerySpec
            {
                QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c"

            };

            var orderDocumentQuery =
                _cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Catalog>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                        _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), query, feedOptions)
                    .AsDocumentQuery();

            var catlog = _cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Catalog>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
            _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), query, feedOptions).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

            var objResponse1 =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Catalog>>(catlog.ToString());


            return objResponse1;
        }
```

error :

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CatalogAPI.Entities.Industy]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'Industy.Id', line 1, position
>   117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var catlog = _cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Catalog>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
            _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), query, feedOptions).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

This line returns a single object. You're trying to parse the string representation of a single object as a list of that object. `JsonConvert` will fail because it won't find an array of object to convert but a single top level JSON object.

You can simply return:

```
return new List<Catalog>{catlog};
```